# How to enable 1920 x 1200 resolution for VGA?

Tags: display, resolution

I have [BenQ T241WA monitor](http://reviews.cnet.com/lcd-monitors/benq-t241wa-lcd-monitor/4505-3174_7-34339052.html). It uses VGA.

With regular cable it is Ok and I can set it native resolution 1920x1200 
Right now I need a longer cable. When I plug longer VGA cable I get max resolution 1600x1200.

I wish to force video adapter to use 1920x1200 instead of 1600x1200. How do I do that?

```
OS: Windows 7 64 bit
Video: NVidia GeForce 9500 GT
Monitor: Generic Non-PnP Monitor
```

With original cable monitor is defined as `Generic PnP Monitor`.
PnP is not working over longer cable.

I ask about how to force Windows 7 to use different resolution then default max 1600x1200.

On Linux I can edit `xorg.conf`. What Windows offer as alternative?

Comment: Check the graphics control center. I have a Dell Ultrasharp 2412 (1920*1200) and it works fine with VGA (i have a GF9500GS at the desktop and an intel |something| laptop card), but both use linux, so it is related to the OS/Driver.

Comment: Thanks @Claudiop If I connect regular short VGA cable then it has all options as well. The problem when I connect longer cable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VGA standard cable has no limit resolution, but a longer cable will catch more noise until a point where it limits the resolution.

So the only thing that limits the resolution is the bandwidth that the cable is able to transfer, if the cable is unable to transfer enought bandwidth to make a complete 1920x1200 screen, the only thing that you can do is buy a better quality cable or use a shorter one.

[Source](http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-comp-hardware/max-resolution-vga-connector-22437.html#post114279)

Comment: I wish to know how to force video adapter to transmit signal with resolution I define. On linux I can do that in xorg.conf. I do not know how to do it in Windows 7.

Comment: Try this: http://www.nvidia.com/object/custom_resolutions.html
I can't test, i don't use windows.

Comment: Have been there many times and have not noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post but I just stumbled upon it so thought I'd pass on some knowledge. 
Not all vga cables have all the cores in them.  Some of them don't have the cores which cary the EDID signal from the display to the computer.  This prevents the computer knowing how it can display so it defaults to basic resolutions and timings.

Comment: This up probably the correct reason. With a poor cable (as in the currently accepted answer) the VGA card should still be able to transmit the 1920x1200 resolution. But with a poor cable you might get ghosting or other poor results.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to a different cable did the trick for me. I didn't expect that to be honest... Windows now automatically used 1920x1200 for the VGA screen.
Cable was the same length but maybe better shielded.

Comment: The correct reason is probably in Nick Yeates answer.

Answer (score 0):

A long VGA (over 25 feet) can over tax your video card on your computer too. Consider a VGA over Ethernet adapter. They are inexpensive and can increase your cable up to 150 feet (or more depending on brand).

Answer (score 0):

I'm confirming that replacing the standard VGA cable with another one (maybe it is higher quality) fix the same issue (missing the resolution 1920x1200) on HP 24" monitor with Windows 10 and intel graphics card.